# Как убрать задержку прогрузки изображений через Picasso?

Tags: java, android

C помощью Retrofit я получаю JSON-данные от сервера и затем все данные записываю в списочный массив типа Item. Затем этот объект кидаю в адаптер RecyclerView, где он уже отображает данные в View-элементах. К сожалению, пока изображения не оказались в кеше, в зависимости от интернета или размера картинки происходит долгая прогрузка изображений, которые неприятны глазу. Как можно увеличить задержку пока изображение окончательно не прогрузится?

**Код фрагмента**

```
private void fillData(View v, Call<List<Item>> call) {

        if (!mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mItemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ProductViewModel.class);

        call.clone().enqueue(new Callback<List<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Item>> call, Response<List<Item>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    items = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i=0; i<response.body().size(); i++) {
                        currentItem = new Item (
                                response.body().get(i).getIdProduct(),
                                response.body().get(i).getName(),
                                response.body().get(i).getPrice(),
                                response.body().get(i).getAmount(),
                                response.body().get(i).getWeight(),
                                response.body().get(i).getImage()
                        );
                        items.add(currentItem);
                        //mItemViewModel.insert(currentItem);
                    }
                    mAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity().getApplication(), R.layout.row, items);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                } else {
                    Log.d("ResponseError", "Error: "+response.code());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Item>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Код адаптера**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (items != null) {
            Item current = items.get(position);
            holder.productName.setText(current.getName());
            holder.productPrice.setText(String.valueOf(current.getPrice()));
            holder.productWeight.setText(String.valueOf(current.getWeight()));
            holder.productAmount.setText(String.valueOf(current.getAmount()));
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(current.getImage())
                    .fit()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(holder.productImage);
        } else {
            Log.d("Holder","Items are empty");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать `Callback`:

```
 .into(holder.productImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Изображения так же прогружаются после создания всех элементов

Comment: @Reboll1011 кроме как использовать изображение заглушку - вы ничего не сделаете...